# open to offers vs. open for offers

Tags: prepositions

I'm working on a claim (slogan) for a website and was wondering whether

- "open to offers we can't refuse" or
- "open for offers we can't refuse" would be more appropiate.

And, yes, I know about the context, it's a play on words / quotes.

Comment: "offer we can't refuse" is normally used to indicate that organized crime is pressuring you to pay protection money.  I think you may want to choose another.

Comment: The use of **to** merely suggests that you are amenable to them (willing to consider them). The use of **for** suggests that you are actively seeking them out (as in *now open for business* signs).